# Structurize html elements into tree like structure using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, tree, structure

I am trying to structurize this html elements into the tree like structure using Java which I will then write into the file. I am not really sure what would be the best way to do this. I already tried to use the for loop to go through all the ids but I don't know how to proceed further.

**Elements that I have:**

```
   <tr id="row_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_0_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_0_0_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_1_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_2_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_3_"></tr>
   <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_4_"></tr>
```

**Goal that I want to achieve:**

```
<tr id="row_0_">
    <tr id="row_0_0_">
        <tr id="row_0_0_0_">
            <tr id="row_0_0_0_0_"></tr>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_0_0_1_">
            <tr id="row_0_0_1_0">
                <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_0_"></tr>
                <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_1_"></tr>
                <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_2_"></tr>
                <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_3_"></tr>
                <tr id="row_0_0_1_0_4_"></tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you know how to construct a tree, you can add a new node with id _X_ by finding out what current node has the longest _prefix_ of the string _X_, and making the new node a child of that one.